# Probability of an event happening while another doesn't

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say you have a bag with $5$ numbers $(1,2,3,4,5)$. What is the probability that I will draw a $1$ if I draw $3$ times (no replacement)? What is the probability that I will draw a $1$ if I draw 3 times, but will not draw a $5$ in any of those $3$ tries (no replacement)?

I know the chance of not getting a $1$ any time is $\frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{4}{5} \cdot\frac{4}{5}$ and so ($1$ - that answer) answers my first question, but I feel like there is a different way to do it (it's a combinatorics class, although this is not a homework question or anything). I don't know how to think about my second question, aside from the fact that the probability will be lower than in the first scenario.

Comment: so you dont have replacement right? when you take out one you wont put it back into the bag. Then whenever you will take out one number than you wont have $5$ numbers anymore in the bag but $4$.

Comment: Correct, although I don't know what to do with that information aside from the fact that it lets me know I'm dealing with conditional probability.

Comment: @user195516 No, you're not dealing with conditional probability; or, at least, you don't have to do so.  You are selecting three items from five and want the probability of selecting `1` and not selecting `5` among those three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The favoured case happens when you draw a `1`, and `2` to `4` on all other draws, of three draws( and never a `5`).   When drawing **without replacement** this is determined by ways to select the favoured items divided by the ways to select any 3 items from 5.

$$\mathsf P(F) = \frac{{1\choose 1}{3\choose 2}}{{5\choose 3}} = \dfrac{3}{10}$$

Answer (score 1):

I see there is already a solution, but just to note that in a simple problem like this, you can easily get to the answer by enumerating the mutually exclusive cases:

1: Draw 1: prob = 1/5

2: Draw 2, 3, 4: prob = 3/4

3: Draw 2, 3, 4: prob = 2/3

total = 6/60

1: Draw 2, 3, 4: prob = 3/5

2: Draw 1: prob = 1/4

3: Draw 2, 3, 4: prob = 2/4

total = 6/60

1: Draw 2, 3, 4: prob = 3/5

2: Draw 2, 3, 4: prob = 2/4

3: Draw 1: prob = 1/3

total = 6/60

Total probability = (6+6+6)/60 = 18/60 = 3/10